# Retrieving Angularjs Http Post data

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs

I am new to angularjs. I made simple app to test authentication by sending user credentials i.e. username and password to server (which is written in php) through post request, But the strange part is that from server I am unable to get data using $_POST instead I can retrieve it through $_GET. I have checked other parts as well like CORS and found no mistake there. A guide would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Here is my angular factory method:**

```
app.factory("loginFact", function($http){
    this.user = {
        isAuthenticated: false,
        name: "",
        token: ""
    }


    this.makeLoginRequest = function(user,pass) {

        var req = {
            method: 'post',
            url: 'http://localhost/login/authenticate.php',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
            },
            params: { username: user, password:pass }
        }


        $http( req ).success(function(data){
            console.log( "Success: " + data )
        }).error(function (data) {
            console.log( "Error: " + data )
        });
    }

    return{
        makeLoginRequest: this.makeLoginRequest
    }

});
```

**Here is my server part:**

```
<?php
header('Accept-Charset: utf-8');
header('Connection: keep-alive');
header('Content-Type: multipart/form-data,');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, content-type');
header('Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With, accept, content-type');


try{


        if(($_POST["username"] == "test") && ($_POST["password"] == "test") ){
                echo "{\"id\": \"700\",    \"user\": {      \"uid\": \"123456\",      \"role\": \"admin\", \"name\": \"waqar\" }}";
                return;
        }else{
                echo "phase1: invalid username/password";
                return;
        }
}catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
}

try{
        $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $data = json_decode($request_body);

        if($data->username == "test" && $data->password == "test"){
                echo "{\"id\": \"700\",    \"user\": {      \"uid\": \"123456\",      \"role\": \"admin\", \"name\": \"waqar\" }}";
                return;
        }
        else{
                echo "phase2: Invalid username/password";
                return;
        }
}catch(Exception $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By sending the data in the `params` object the data will be send in the headers as query parameters (in the URL - `?key1=value1&key2=value2`).

You must instead send them in the body by using `data` object key:

```
var req = {
    method: 'post',
    url: 'http://localhost/login/authenticate.php',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "multipart/form-data"
    },
    data: { username: user, password:pass }
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) for more details.

If I understood correctly, in the comment you're asking: why put the parameters into the request's body rather than in the URL?

You could send them in the URL, but you will have some drawbacks:

- Encoding is better in body than in the URL
- You can send more data in the body, since URL's length it's usually limited (varies on the system but around 2000 chars)
- It is easier to spoof the URL
- Systems usually save the URL in their logs so you risk to expose your client's accounts if someone sees the logs (Consider that they will be saved in plain text even if you encrypt/hash them in the database)
- Considering the previous point, in some countries it might be illegal to log sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks it's working now. Also I would have to use Post method for authentication but what if I want to send data in Query String format just like Get Method does it?

Comment: I updated the answer since I'm not allowed to write too much here.